# Oval in picture environment has discontinuous corners

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to create a rounded rectangle so I used the `\oval` command inside the picture environment but the corners do not connect and are of a different thickness. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1mm}
\begin{picture}(1600,1000)
  \put(850,475){\oval(1300,750)}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of oval]

Comment: someone is bound to tell you to use tikz but you could load pict2e package and the the ovals will be drawn via back end graphics calls rather than using characters, without needing to change the syntax.

Comment: It depends on your PDF Viewer... Try to zoom in & out or check it in a different viewer

Comment: @karlkoeller You're right, it looks fine when view with adobe reader however I would like a universal solution because I don't know what viewer users will have when they view my file.

Comment: Note that you get the warning `LaTeX Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable` because you have the `\unitlength` too small. With `pict2e` the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\usepackage{pict2e}` solved the problem.

[image]